# How to make a secure Online shop

Tags: php, e-commerce, security

I plan to run an online shop and will write script by myself (I'm php developer). However,my worries are:

1. How to ensure the secure payment online?
2. To ensure the application safe, if need to buy a server to host app rather than using shared hosting?
3. How to prevent hacker to change data in the database (i.e. price, content)?

Any sugeestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not handle the online payments yourself, unless you are a **big** company that has a lot of previous experience with it and you know exactly what you are doing. On top of that you'd need many acquirer connections and implement all of these in order to be able to process the payments. Also you'd have the need to be PCI Compliant...

And even then you might get hacked (look at what happened to Sony that had his PS3 creditcard database hacked).

So my advice would be to go with an online Payment Provider such as [Ogone](http://www.ogone.com). They give you a complete API to allow you to receive online payments through many different payment methods and you do not have to worry about any security issues.

That is if you want to develop the entire webshop yourself (which is perfectly possible). If you want to save some time you can make use of several eCommerce solutions such as [Magento](http://www.magento.com). They also work together with Ogone, so you won't have to worry about security issues either this way.

As for the data changes, you should make sure that this is impossible by using a good password and making sure that no SQL injection can be done on ANY page.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a whole e-comm site from scratch will be one epic task my friend.

I highly suggest you look into some e-comm platforms, namely Magento

It will save you development time and ensure that the application runs in a secure manner.

HTH

Comment: For small team it is fairly easy task.

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont have to do that yourself, the gateways like paypal, ideal, cc etc.. will do that for you and give you a nice response when everything has happened safely
2. Well no, not really, ofcourse as long as your server isnt physically in the same room as you are in, its prone to hosts snooping in. So just go with a solid host and you're fine. If they leave your database vulnerable to other people on the server: sue em.
3. sharks!

What Im trying to say is: get yourself some Magenta or Joomla/VM and you're all fine... Not being hacked is a big issue if you have to ask these questions :D